# Changing Settings.System constant to SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, system, constants

I want to get rid of all the system contants in Frameworks Base therefore I wanted to ask if I can make this system constant independent

```
Settings.System.SMART_PHONE_CALLER, 0);
```

can be changed to

```
SharedPreferences.SMART_PHONE_CALLER, 0);
```

Your answer is appreciated!

Comment: Or can I simply change to System.SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. These constants are determined by the OS and you can only access read them.

> System settings, containing miscellaneous system preferences. This table holds simple name/value pairs. There are convenience functions for accessing individual settings entries.

[Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html)

Comment: Instead of Settings.System can I use Settings.SharedPreferences because I really want to get rid of those frameworks base constants